# Calculate the average of marks obtained and store it in list format and return back to function

Tags: python, list, average

xyz school had conducted the annual examination for the 5th standard class and they want to calculate the grade for the students who all attended in the annual examination. each student has 5 subject marks. let's help them to calculate the grade for the students. define a function called calculategrade which takes a parameter. the first parameter is students marks as a list. the function definition code stub is given in the editor. calculate grade for all students given in the list, store into the list, and return it. steps to calculate the grade for students iterate each student, calculate the average score, and find the grade based on the average of a student store the grade for each student into a list, and return it.

Here is what I tried

```
def calculateGrade(students_marks):
    grade = []
    for x in range(len(students_marks)):
        avg = (sum(students_marks[x]))//len(students_marks[x])
        if(avg >= 90):
            grade.append('A+')
        elif avg in range(80,90):
            grade.append('A')
        elif avg in range(70,80):
            grade.append('B')
        elif avg in range(60,70):
            grade.append('C')
        elif avg in range(50,60):
            grade.append('D')
        elif (avg < 40):
            grade.append('F')
    return grade

if __name__ == '__main__':
fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

students_marks_rows = int(input().strip())
students_marks_columns = int(input().strip())

students_marks = []

for _ in range(students_marks_rows):
    students_marks.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

result = calculateGrade(students_marks)
fptr.write('\n'.join(result))
fptr.write('\n')

fptr.close()
```

User Input2
5
[50,68,88,85,25]
[45,85,88,56,14]

Expected Output
C
D

My Output
C

Comment: What is your question? When you inspected/printed values and/or conditions at various points in your program was there an obvious place where it was misbehaving? Did you test your function with known inputs? Does it work?

Comment: `calculateGrade([[50,68,88,85,25], [45,85,88,56,14]])` works.

Comment: I am not getting the desired output. as there are two list entered i.e ([[50,68,88,85,25], [45,85,88,56,14]]) grade for both the input should be displayed but can only see one grade as a output

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your example.

Comment: Also you could simply iterate over the 2D array like `for x in students_marks` rather than introducing `range()` and `len()`. Then it would be `avg = sum(x) // len(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm It's weird. It works ok for me but what might be the problem is the fptr variable, although I'm not sure.

```
import os

def calculateGrade(students_marks):
    grade = []
    for x in range(len(students_marks)):
        avg = (sum(students_marks[x]))//len(students_marks[x])
        print(avg)
        if(avg >= 90):
            grade.append('A+')
        elif avg in range(80,90):
            grade.append('A')
        elif avg in range(70,80):
            grade.append('B')
        elif avg in range(60,70):
            grade.append('C')
        elif avg in range(50,60):
            grade.append('D')
        elif (avg < 40):
            grade.append('F')
    return grade


students_marks_rows = int(input().strip())
students_marks_columns = int(input().strip())

students_marks = []

for _ in range(students_marks_rows):
    students_marks.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

result = calculateGrade(students_marks)
print(result)
fptr = open("text.txt","w")
fptr.write('\n'.join(result))
fptr.write('\n')

fptr.close()
```

This is how I defined this variable, and the output is:

C
D

Comment: the output you got was due to print(result) statement. that statement was added by mistake. I have edited the code now and removed the print(result) statement. now only 1 output is generated and displayed.

Comment: This is my output in a text file. The problem might be here os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'] but I don't know .

Comment: The problem is of Hacker rank and only function is editable so os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH' is non editable

Answer (score 1):

```
elif (avg < 40): 
    grade.append('F') 
return grade
```

Here you had mentioned `avg<40`, but it should be `avg<50`. Why? Because you had not mentioned the case where the score is ranging between 40-50. That is the reason you are getting only one output. Please try to change it to `avg<50` and run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok, but last step needs to be modified, instead of avg < 40 for grade "F" condition it should be avg <50

Below is the one which I have tried and it worked:

elif (avg < 50):
grade.append('F')

Answer (score 0):

Its just a matter of statement 'return grade'...if u indent it in if-elif statement you will get only one grade and if u indent it with for statement you will get the desired result that is two grades

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculateGrade(students_marks):
    result=[]
    marks=students_marks
    for x in marks:
        avg=sum(x)/len(x)
        if avg >=90:
            grade="A+"
            result.append(grade)
        elif avg >= 80 and avg <90:
            grade="A"
            result.append(grade)
        elif avg >= 70 and avg <80:
            grade="B"
            result.append(grade)
        elif avg >= 60 and avg <70:
            grade="C"
            result.append(grade)
        elif avg >= 50 and avg <60:
            grade="D"
            result.append(grade)
        elif avg < 50:
            grade="F"
            result.append(grade)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    
    students_marks_rows = int(input().strip())
    students_marks_columns = int(input().strip())
    
    students_marks = []
    
    for _ in range(students_marks_rows):
        students_marks.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))
    
    result = calculateGrade(students_marks)
    
    fptr.write('\n'.join(result))
    fptr.write('\n')
    
    fptr.close()
```

Comment: Your code might be a bit easier to read if you used chained comparisons like `elif 80 <= avg < 90:`. I've fixed your formatting and have implemented what I think would be your intended indentation, but you should check it. Finally, please consider an edit to add to explanation as to how this code answers the question.

Comment: You don't need to repeat `result.append(grade)` so many times, just add it at the end of the if block so whatever the value of `grade` var it will be appended.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).